# Google maps database bounds entry for the USA incorrect or my code is missing something

Tags: javascript, database, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, bounds

I am having an issue with the bounds of some countries returned by Google's geocoder.

The example code below queries Google database for 'USA' and uses the returned bounds to set up a rectangle to visualize the result. The rectangle covers only a part of the south-east mainland USA.

Bounds returned (SWlat, SWlng, NElat, NElng):
((29.321898, -95.71289100000001), (37.09024, -90.90566230000002))

Probably I am overlooking something in the code, any suggestions or ideas what it might be ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">   
</script>

<style type="text/css">
     #map-canvas, html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100%; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map, 
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder() ,
    rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle() ;

    function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map (document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -95)
        });         

        geocoder.geocode( {'address': 'USA'}, function(results, status){
             if (status == 'OK') {
                 rectangle.setBounds (results[0]["geometry"]["bounds"]) ;
                 rectangle.setMap (map);
                 console.log ( rectangle.getBounds().toString() );
             }
        }); 
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);   

</script> 
</head>
<body>  
     <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: That does look incorrect.  I usually use the viewport returned by the geocoder, not the bounds.

Comment: Yes, that's the strange as it is Google's definition of bounds and viewport:
- viewport stores the recommended viewport for the returned result.
- bounds stores the LatLngBounds which can fully contain (!) the returned result, which apparently contradicts this result (provided something is missing in the code or its tuning)

Comment: for the US, bounds (should) contain Alaska and Hawaii (and other "US places"), the viewport shows just the continental US.